# Issue installing input-fonts with nixOS, how to use 'nix-store --add-fixed'?

Tags: linux, fonts, nixos

NixOS version: `20.09.3765.d6f63659a70 (Nightingale)`

I am trying to install [Input Fonts](https://input.djr.com/download/) on NixOS (which I'm pretty new to).

I seem to be unable to install input-fonts on NixOS even though I have the following lines in my /etc/nixos/configuration.nix

```
fonts.fonts = with pkgs; [
  input-fonts
];

nixpkgs.config.allowUnfree = true;
nixpkgs.config.input-fonts.acceptLicense = true;
```

When trying to `nixos-rebuild switch`, I get the following error:

```
***
Unfortunately, we cannot download file Input-Font.zip automatically.
Please go to https://input.fontbureau.com/download/ to download it yourself, and add it to the Nix store
using either
  nix-store --add-fixed sha256 Input-Font.zip
or
  nix-prefetch-url --type sha256 file:///path/to/Input-Font.zip

***
```

Looks like the issue is that there is no static download URL accessible from the Fontbureau page.

So I have downloaded the zip manually and run `nix-store --add-fixed sha256 Input-Font.zip`, but frankly I don't really know what to do with the output and the docs for --add-fixed don't really shed any light on it for me.

I get an output like this: `/nix/store/7vqs2n6hrnwgd9hf6rxyhg5hx5qnrd2s-Input-Font.zip`

Is anyone more familiar with installing packages in this way able to shed light on what to do with this?

---

Alternatively I could install the fonts from the files I've downloaded manually, but I am also unclear on how to do that, NixOS docs state:

```
Adding personal fonts to ~/.fonts doesn't work

The ~/.fonts directory is being deprecated upstream[1]. It already doesn't work in NixOS.

The new preferred location is in $XDG_DATA_HOME/fonts, which for most users will resolve to ~/.local/share/fonts
```

I have tried adding the font files in ~/.local/share/fonts too, but they still don't get recognized when I try to use them in any config.

---

Any help on either method for getting these fonts working would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK turns out I just had a few more linux commands to learn to install fonts manually.

In the end this is what I did:

Moved all the TTF files for Input Mono into ~/.local/share/fonts, and ran the following commands (seperately):

`fc-cache -f -v`
`fc-list | grep "Input"`

fc-cache seemed to flush the cache for fonts, fc-list with the grep printed out the names and styles of the installed Input fonts which I could then use in config.

Alacritty config was able to switch the fonts out on the fly, the nix config font changes required a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

After following those instructions, you're supposed to retry the installation.  If the hash matched exactly, you will get past that error you got.

EDIT: it seems that `input-fonts` was broken and that's why it wouldn't work; please follow https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/pull/118665